# cannot sorting array correctly in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting

I create this function to sort my data in `array`, when I sort it by the ID it's working just fine, but when I tried to sort it by name nothing is happening.

Anyone can help with this problem? thanks before

```
const sortData = (params) => {
    if (params === "id-asc") {
      array.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.id - b.id;
      });
    }
    if (params === "id-des") {
      array.sort((a, b) => {
        return b.id - a.id;
      });
    }
    if (params === "name-asc") {
      array.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.name - b.name;
      });
    }
    if (params === "name-des") {
      array.sort((a, b) => {
        return b.name - a.name;
      });
    }
    setArrayData(array);
  };
```

Comment: Are you sure the `name` is a numeric value? Or you'd only get `NaN`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `name`s are strings, you can't just compare them by subtraction.

Instead do `return (a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1);` or, maybe preferably [use `localeCompare`, so `return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)